How to make the OOM killer target processes with high nice values?
I would like to know how to configure the OOM killer to first kill processes that have a high nice value. My usecase for this is that I have some background processes where I don't mind them getting killed, but I'd like to preserve my main programs.
I have read How does the OOM killer decide which process to kill first?, and as far as I understand the OOM killer considers three factors:

how much memory is hypothetically available to a process
what percentage of that limit is the process currently using
the process' oom_score_adj

So I guess the real question is: how can I set oom_score_adj automatically based on the nice value of the process?

personally, I'd first make sure I first make use of cgroup2 scopes as far as possible – in a high-pressure situation, that should limit the members  of that group. It'd seem that's something you might reasonably want to do for CPU time limiting instead of just the nice values, anyways :)

If you are already starting your niced processes via a systemd unit, then you can set OOMScoreAdjust=... in the [Service] section.
